# Fade in on scroll doesn't work in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile-website

I am using this code to add class "show" to my images so when a person scrolls down, images show up. It works on desktop (tested in chrome, with mousescroll and with touch simulation) but it does not work in chrome on mobile device. Swipe(scroll with touch) is not detected. Page goes down but images dont get that .show. I am using this inside fullpage.js+iscroll.js page.

You can try this at: http://www.vinarijapantic.com/apps/onePage/project.html

Any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     function showImages(el) {
         var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
         $(el).each(function() {
             var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;

             var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
             if (topOfWindow + windowHeight - 250 > thisPos) {
                 $(this).addClass("show");
             }
         });
     }



     /*full page library */
     var SCROLLING_SPEED = 600;
     $('#fullpage').fullpage({

         scrollOverflow: true,
         css3: true,
         controlArrows: true,
         loopHorizontal: false,
         easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
         easingcss3: 'ease-out',
         autoScrolling: true,
         scrollingSpeed: SCROLLING_SPEED,
         //anchors:['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3']
         afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {

         },
         afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {

             if (slideIndex == 0) {
                 $('.slide-' + index).addClass('show');
             } else {
                 $('.slide').removeClass('show');

             }
             if ($('.bigScroll').hasClass('active') && $('.bigScroll').closest('.section').hasClass('active')) {
                 console.log($(".bigScroll").height());
                 showImages('.bigScroll img');
                 $('.fp-scrollable').scroll(function() {
                     showImages('.bigScroll img');
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: What is that "fullpage" plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Enable JavaScript on mobile web

There are situations where the browsers throw an error like
"when trying to access ------- on a mobile device"
it means the web browser on your device needs to have JavaScript turned on before you load the page.

To turn on JavaScript, open the settings menu for your mobile web browser and look for the JavaScript option.

Comment: I very seriously doubt that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not worth the technical debt to build your own lazy loading plugin (which is a colloquial name for what you are trying to do). Use a contributed jQuery plugin instead.

I've used this one with great success in the past: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

It's really easy to use - just add an `data` attribute to your HTML img tag and instantiate the plugin with a simple jQuery reference.

HTML:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg">
```

JS:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

Comment: Will try to implement with Iscroll, any suggestions? p.s. I am always open for different solutions, thx for suggestion.

Comment: iscroll.js isn't something I've used before but I just read over its documentation (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) and it only applies itself to the wrapper of the iscroll section you want. It shouldn't interfere with lazy loading, as they act on different elements and would be instantiated separately.